# Natural join on two tables with different number of columns that working properly

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, natural-join

I'm trying to understand why natural join is not working properly in sql on my two tables:

```
bookno |        title
--------+----------------------
2001 | Databases
2012 | Geometry
2010 | Philosophy
2008 | DataScience
2011 | Anthropology
2003 | Networks
2013 | RealAnalysis
2006 | SQL
2002 | OperatingSystems
2007 | ProgrammingLanguages
2009 | Calculus
2005 | DiscreteMathematics
2014 | Topology
2004 | AI
(14 rows)
```

and

```
price | bookno |  title   | b2price | sid  |   sname
-------+--------+----------+---------+------+-----------
70 |   2014 | Topology |      70 | 1022 | Joeri
80 |   2012 | Geometry |      80 | 1008 | Emma
80 |   2012 | Geometry |      80 | 1010 | Linda
80 |   2012 | Geometry |      80 | 1020 | Ahmed
80 |   2012 | Geometry |      80 | 1004 | Chin
80 |   2012 | Geometry |      80 | 1023 | Chris
80 |   2012 | Geometry |      80 | 1007 | Catherine
80 |   2012 | Geometry |      80 | 1017 | Ellen
70 |   2014 | Topology |      70 | 1023 | Chris
80 |   2012 | Geometry |      80 | 1012 | Eric
80 |   2012 | Geometry |      80 | 1006 | Ryan
80 |   2012 | Geometry |      80 | 1002 | Maria
80 |   2012 | Geometry |      80 | 1014 | Filip
80 |   2012 | Geometry |      80 | 1005 | John
80 |   2012 | Geometry |      80 | 1009 | Jan
80 |   2012 | Geometry |      80 | 1013 | Lisa
80 |   2012 | Geometry |      80 | 1011 | Nick
80 |   2012 | Geometry |      80 | 1003 | Anna
(18 rows)
```

The second table is table made using a couple of cross-joins and different tables. Shouldn't the result of this natural join be:

```
bookno |        title
--------+----------------------
2012 | Geometry
2014 | Topology
```

But instead, all it's outputting is the first table over again. Why is this the case? The exact code is:

```
select distinct b.bookno, b.title
from book b, student s
natural join (select distinct b1.price, b2.bookno, b2.title, b2.price, s1.sid, s1.sname
from buys t cross join book b1 cross join book b2 cross join student s1
where b1.price > 50 and s1.sid = t.sid and 
t.bookno = b1.bookno and b2.price = b1.price) q0;
```

Comment: simple Inner join should be sufficient right?. why use cross join twice?

Comment: This code was written as a literal translation to create an equivalent relational algebra SQL code. That's why the multiple cross joins are used

Comment: Comma is cross join but with lower precedence than JOIN keyword joins. So the natural join is done first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is (horrible) old syntax produces a cross join between book and student:

```
select distinct b.bookno, b.title
from book b, student s
```

rewritten for explicit join syntax it is:

```
select distinct b.bookno, b.title
from book b CROSS JOIN student s
```

But if that is literally how the query is structured all you would get in return would be the `bookno` and `title`, which is effectively the same as:

```
select b.bookno, b.title
from book b
```

and the rest of you query is just noise.

nb: If your result repeats bookno/title then you haven't copied the *exact* query into the questions

Comment: No it does not do that. Comma is cross join but with lower precedence than explicit JOINs. So the natural join is done then the cross join.